# Create a cross reference table using Golden record and associate other records to the record

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I have ranked all the rows based on the created date column and have the rank indicated on the table as below

main table

[image: main table]

I would like to create a cross-reference table with the golden record as the recurring column and the other two records as associated records as below.

output desired

[image: output desired]

I would like to know how I can achieve this using SQL.

I have tried creating a seperate table with all ID numbers (Rank = 1) and then joining it with the main table to get the ones with rank 1,2 and 3 associated with it. But it doesnt seem to work as I intend to.

output

[image: output]

Comment: The images you've linked to your 'output desired' and 'output' are the same - can you give the queries you've tried to get your desired output?

Comment: So which dbms is this?  SQL Server and Oracle are completely different product.

Comment: sql server is what I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested but something like this should work.  You might want to add a name_id field.

```
    select b.id_number,a.id_number
    from table a
    join table b on a.name=b.name
    where b.rank=1
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!! . Thank you :)
I was trying 

select b.id_number,a.id_number
    from table a
    join table b on a.name=b.name
    where b.rank= b.rank